# Is there an IBM Cloud weather API to get historical weather data for 2 months for a particular region?

Tags: ibm-cloud, weather-api

The Weather Company(TWC)'s API are generally comprehensive as per the needs of a typical weather data based application.

As the weather company now a part of IBM, I assume there will be an API that can tell us about the history of weather over a city for the past 2-3 months. We want weather history data for one of our interactive forecast applications.

Is there an IBM Cloud weather API to get historical weather data for 2 months for a particular region?

Thanks!

Comment: You see, this is the fundamental problem with Stackoverflow. We don't recommend frameworks or programs, but here we go, users giving you upvotes and everything.

Comment: @Krythic I thought stackoverflow will be the best place to get an answer for this.

Comment: Here is a link to an explanation of the types of questions to ask on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In the IBM Cloud there are a few [Weather Company APIs](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/weather-company-data) available. You can find many more directly from the Weather Company [here](https://business.weather.com/products/weather-data-packages). This  includes an historical API that will return the historic observations closest to the location (lat,lon) requested.